# Linear Elliptic PDE Variable Coefficients Non-Separating Variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, power-series, maple, elliptic-equations, legendre-functions

I am trying to obtain Analytical solutions for the following Linear Elliptic PDE in the dependent variable U(x,y) having variable coefficients. 'x' is a (pseudo) radial coordinate, and 'y' is an angular variable. The PDE is:

f(x,y)*diff(U(x,y), x, x) + g(x,y)*diff(U(x,y), y, y) + h(x,y)*diff(U(x,y), x) +  k(x,y)*diff(U(x,y), y) + l(x,y)*U(x,y) = 0

where the the coefficients f, g, h, k, and l are polynomials in both x and y as follows (and a is an additional parameter):

f(x,y) = (x^2-1)*( -1 + (x^2 + a^2 *y^2)*p(a)^2 )

g(x,y) = -(y^2-1)*( -1 + (x^2 + a^2 *y^2)*p(a)^2 )

h(x,y) = 2*x*( -1 + (2 - x^2 + a^2*y^2)*p(a)^2 )

k(x,y) = 2*y*( 1 + (-x^2 + (-2 + y^2)*a^2)*p(a)^2 )

l(x,y) = -2(y^2*a^2 - a^2 - x^2 - 1)*p(a)^2

I am currently attempting to solve this using a separation of variable approach, but the PDE will not separate. Only in the limiting case of a=0 (with p(a) becoming p(a=0)), does the PDE admit a variable-separation solution with Legendre's equation in y being one of the resulting ODEs. That reduced PDE was solved using a combination of l=0 and l=2 Legendre Polynomials.

But the full equation does not admit a variable-separation approach, at least when I use MAPLE 18. Is there a different method to variable separation that could be used to obtain analytical solutions to the full PDE?

Could a Power Series work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have now stated the explicit form of the PDE and my aim of solving it in closed form.